# Is it possible to write a prototype for a "FileList" object type in javascript to construct and add a "File" object into it?

Tags: javascript, selenium, phantomjs, prototype

I never write a prototype before and i do not understand the concept of the callback functions. 
The project i am working on is to automate the firmware update process of the routers that my company is using with the help of python, selenium and phantomjs.

The firmware file is processing by a javascript by an onsubmit event, before it is send to the target. Therefore i can not send the file with a simple request.

[image: The Screen of the elements in the document]

The router's script is checking for the form parameters and if the parameters are valid it starts the update process.

As you can see from my dev-tools window i could managed to create the firmware file as a File object which is stored in a variable called `data_transfer_object.dataTransfer.files` which is a type of **File Object**

*What i am trying to do is to assign this **File Object** to the **input[type="file"]** form element which has a name of "firmware".*

To manage this i should assign the `document.getElementById("firmware").files` to a `FileList object` but i have a File Object which are items of a FileList object.

- Is it possible to write any kind of a prototype to create a FileList object and add File Object's inside it?

or

- Is there any other way that i can manage to assign my File Object to the input[type="file"] form element?

By the way none of the following assignments are working:

```
document.getElementById("firmware").files[0] = data_transfer_object.dataTransfer.files
document.getElementById("firmware").files.item[0]= data_transfer_object.dataTransfer.files
document.getElementById("firmware")[0] = data_transfer_object.dataTransfer.files
```

Thank you!

Comment: How is this a python question exactly ? (=> tag removed).

Comment: I am trying to manage this with python with the selenium library and phantomjs webdriver therefore i thought there might be someone who use python with selenium and phantomjs can point me some other directions. Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to simulate? For security reasons, it's not possible to add files to a file list from the page. Though there are workarounds with Selenium depending on the action you need to simulate.  For instance you can directly assign a file to a `<input type="file">` with `element.send_keys('path to file')`

Comment: Thank you Florent! I have tried it but it did not work for me therefore i have started to dig around other options. I don't know the reason why it didn't worked in the first place when i tried it but if you say so then i will try harder to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

As Florent B. stated that: 
For security reasons, it's not possible to add files to a file list from the page. Though there are workarounds with Selenium depending on the action you need to simulate. For instance you can directly assign a file to a `<input type="file">` with

> element.send_keys('path to file')

Selenium command ***send_keys*** is solved my question. Why it didn't work for me was because of an incorrect path.

Thank's goes to
**Florent B.**